# In PHP how to get time/date when cookie was set/created?

Tags: php, cookies

How to get the cookie's birthday/time in PHP?

The cookie itself contains other data, so was wondering if there is a way to get the exact date and h:m:s when it was created without having to create a second cookie just to hold that information?

I searched but too much interference with the other keywords: set, time, cookie, date that's showing answers, but not to this question.

Comment: What is the problem with creating additional cookies? Why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: Making sure I haven't missed any new advances in cookie technology first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to create an array, serialize that array to a string and store the serialized string inside the cookie:

```
$mycookieArray = array('cookiedata'=>'some data','creationTime'=>new DateTime());
$mycookiedata = serialize($mycookieArray);
```

Then, everytime you want to load the correct you have to unserialize the array from the cookiedata:

```
$mycookieArray = unserialize($mycookiedata);
```

Comment: You are assuming I am allowed to change the original cookie, but alas, with that power comes great responsibility I was told that takes years to earn. :(

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a day or two, if no one thinks of anything better I will check you off.

Comment: Sorry, even what I commented earlier wasn't a correct reference. (i.e. metadata for a specific cookie vs global cookie settings)! According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839732/get-cookie-expiration) SO link, only name and value are stored!