# is it possible to rewrite the value of stored cookie in javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

is it possible to rewrite the value of stored cookie? If so How to do that?

My exact case is,
I have created a cookie with some **PATH**(frm user,which i don know probably). I have to rewrite the value of this cookie somewhere else. I can just create a cookie wit same name but the problem here is i don know the PATH value.

1. Either i should get the PATH of the stored cookie..
2. else, i should re-write the existing cookie

Any help would be most welcome
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [DOC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#page-10)

> If the user agent receives a new cookie with the same cookie-name,
> domain-value, and path-value as a cookie that it has already
> stored,the existing cookie is evicted and replaced with the new
> cookie. Notice that servers can delete cookies by sending the user
> agent a new cookie with an Expires attribute with a value in the past.

So, What @Royi Namir has posted is the solution. Coz there is no specific way to rewrite cookie other than setting it again.

Refer this answer in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802760/is-it-possible-to-get-a-stored-cookies-path) regarding getting path info of a stored cookie

Comment: Hi. thanks for ur reply.. if i'm not going to giv the same path.. The existing cookie will not be overriden rite?

Comment: Again From the DOC:`If the server omits the Path attribute, the user agent will use the "directory" of the request-uri's path component as the default value`. So if the cookie you wish to delete takes the same path as the default value you might get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

you can save cookie like that :

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires) {  
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/" + ((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString());
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks.. i hav to re-write the existing cookie